# Should I release the returned IMFSample of an internally allocated MFT output buffer?

Tags: c++, memory-management, ms-media-foundation

**Media Foundation Transform  objects (MFT)** may implement an output buffer allocation model where the buffers are allocated internally by the MFT object.

If this is the case, the internally allocated buffer is returned via the `pSample` member of an `MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER` structure that is passed to the `IMFTransform::ProcessOutput()` method.

From the [MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms697247(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation:

```
typedef struct _MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER {
  DWORD         dwStreamID;
  IMFSample     *pSample;
  DWORD         dwStatus;
  IMFCollection *pEvents;
} MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER;
```

> **pSample**
>
> Pointer to the `IMFSample` interface. Before calling `ProcessOutput`,
>   set this member equal to a valid `IMFSample` pointer or `NULL`. See
>   Remarks for more information.

From the [IMFTransform::ProcessOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms704014(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation:

**Output Buffers**

> The MFT returns output data for a stream through the `pSample` member
>   of the `MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER` structure. This structure member is a
>   pointer to the `IMFSample` interface of a media sample. (See Media
>   Samples.) **The media sample is allocated either by the caller or by the
>   MFT, depending on the MFT's allocation model.** To find the allocation
>   model, call `IMFTransform::GetOutputStreamInfo` and examine the
>   `dwFlags` member of the `MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_INFO` structure

...

> If `pSample` is `NULL` and `dwFlags` does not contain the
>   `MFT_PROCESS_OUTPUT_DISCARD_WHEN_NO_BUFFER`, the MFT provides a sample
>   for the output data. The MFT sets `pSample` to point to the sample
>   that it provides. The MFT can either allocate a new sample or re-use
>   an input sample.

**The documentation does not mention if the returned `IMFSample` interface in this case should be released.**  It seems this is not the case, since the documentation is very explicit that any events returned via the same struct should be released by the caller.

From the [MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms697247(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation:

> **pEvents**
>
> Before calling `ProcessOutput`, set this member to `NULL`. On output,
>   the MFT might set this member to a valid `IMFCollection`
>   interface pointer. The pointer represents a collecton that contains
>   zero or more events. To get each event, call
>   `IMFCollection::GetElement` and query the returned `IUnknown` pointer
>   for the `IMFMediaEvent` interface. **When the `ProcessOutput` method
>   returns, the caller is responsible for releasing the `IMFCollection`
>   pointer if the pointer is not `NULL`.**

**Can somebody confirm if the returned `IMFSample` interface should be released or not?**

I think that If we should not release the returned interface, it should be documented explicitly, as it goes against the established COM way of releasing the interface once we have finished using it.

Comment: I confirm that the documentation is not clear... 
This permissive situation creates architectural problems about COM and about releasing resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The caller is responsible to release the sample if the pointer was initialized with a non-NULL value by the MFT (as opposed to buffer allocated by the caller - in which case the MFT uses it but does not need to AddRef it in the structure).

Code snippet below is good for all three models:

> - If the MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_PROVIDES_SAMPLES flag is present, the MFT allocates the media sample.
> - If the MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_CAN_PROVIDE_SAMPLES flag is present, the caller can optionally provide a media sample. If pSample is NULL, the MFT will allocate the media sample.
> - If neither of these two flags is present, the caller must allocate the media sample.

Note that the documentation does not mention a scenario where caller provides a sample pointer, and MFT replaces it with its own.

(the code is not to be perfect though, just an illustration of reference counting; if there is *a priori* information that samples are caller's then there is no need to do Attach/Detach thing, of course)

```
CComPtr<IMFSample> pSample;
// pSample is NULL or not
MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER Buffer;
Buffer.pSample = pSample.Detach();
// ...
const HRESULT nResult = pTransform->ProcessOutput(..., &Buffer, ...);
pSample.Attach(Buffer.pSample);
// pSample holds a valid properly ref'fed pointer
// No need to use Buffer.pSample below
```